# img resize, but width will stop at 600

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML

```
<div>
    <div style="overflow: auto">
        <img class="preview_img" src="/myImg" />
        <img class="preview_img" src="/myImg2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
btnZoomIn.click(function () {
    previewImg.each(function () {
        var width = $(this).width();
        var height = $(this).height();

        var newWidth = width * 1.2;
        var newHeight = height * 1.2;

        $(this).css('width', newWidth);
        $(this).css('height', newHeight);
        // $(this).width(newWidth);
        // $(this).height(newHeight);
    });
});
```

I want to resize the img when the button onclick, the width will stop on 600px,

but the height can up unlimit.

I did not set any max-width property(attribute)

Comment: In the future, make sure to supply a more interactive excerpt of your code (like JSFiddle or Codepen). This makes is much easier for us.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe inherit `max-width` from other element, so add inline style to prevent `max-width` rule:

```
previewImg.each(function () {
    $(this).css('max-width','none');
});

btnZoomIn.click(function () {

    previewImg.each(function () {
        var width = $(this).width();
        var height = $(this).height();

        var newWidth = width * 1.2;
        var newHeight = height * 1.2;

        $(this).css('width', newWidth);
        $(this).css('height', newHeight);
        // $(this).width(newWidth);
        // $(this).height(newHeight);
    });
});
```

Then if problem exist check `max-width` or `width` of parents.

Comment: I check my max-width setting, it did not inherit from other elements.
and I try the method you suggested. The problem still exist.

Comment: Check parents for `max-width` or `width` proprty. Maybe a parent has fixed width.